# word: fridges that keep things hot (and not cold)

Tags: word-choice

What's the word for what looks like a fridge but actually keeps things warm/hot instead of cold?

hot fridge?

Comment: Note that since the OP did not specify keeping food warm, "Incubator" might be an appropriate word. One would put microorganisms in a fridge-looking incubator.

Comment: food warmer, hotbox, or thermos are all terms that come to mind

Comment: I'd been to Tromso once and let me tell you, every fridge there keeps the food warmer than outside!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably referring to a [food warmer](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5825763_food-warmer_.html):

> Heat lamps, hot boxes, steam tables, soup kettles and display warmers are just *some types of food warmers* that currently exist. Heat lamps, steam tables and soup kettles often leave food exposed in some way while they keep it warm. Hot boxes and display warmers fully enclose foods.

Source:http://www.ehow.com/facts_5825763_food-warmer_.html

Comment: "Hot box" is the term that came immediately to my mind. Admittedly, what little food-service experience I have is now over 20 years old, so terminology might have changed.

Answer (score 6):

Since "fridge" is short for refrigerator, it's doubtful you can use "hot fridge" because that would kinda mean "hot cold".  An enclosed container that heats or keeps food warm is an *oven* or a *warming oven* - as shown  below:

[image]

Comment: These are also known as a `warming drawer`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you just want to keep warm food that is ready for eating, or whether a warm environment is required as part of the food preparation.

For most of us at home, the oven on a low setting suffices for doing this.

For those involved in the food industry, there are of course more specialised equipment. Josh61 has mentioned a food warmer. If you need to have a warm environment for yeasted dough to rise, you can also get a **proofing cabinet**.

Comment: The question isn't what to use to keep food warm, but what to call an appliance that keeps food warm.

Comment: @Marthaª: You're splitting hairs, and in this case I don't think the two questions are very different. The question concerns "something that looks like a fridge but makes things hot", but to what is being referred? Maybe it's a convection oven, heat lamps, or a commercial "food warmer", but unless we're talking about an existing appliance it makes little difference whether we call it a "hot fridge", "warmbox", or perhaps even "defridgerator".

Comment: @meustrus: I don't think it's splitting hairs to point out that the question Peter is answering is actually off-topic for this site. And dunno about you, but I'm not sure I ever want to meet a heat lamp that resembles a refrigerator. (We *are* talking about an existing appliance, btw, or at least an existing class of appliances.)

Comment: You know, the part after **proofing cabinet** actually seems a little marketing-speak, so perhaps if that were removed this would stand alone as an example of a type of appliance that keeps food warm.

Comment: I will remove the bit after 'proofing cabinet' then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like a Hot Cupboard?  this is a mainly for keeping plates warm, but can be used on food also. [image]

Comment: Have you got a link that directs to the expression *hot cupboard*? Is it a term with which you more familiar? A lot of the answers posted are very similar in content, so yours need to "stand out" more.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking about food, but your question is sufficiently vague that it could also refer to an *incubator* — a warming appliance usually used in a biomedical facility.  ([Examples](http://www.panasonic-biomedical.co.uk/Prod_Laboratory_Incubators.htm))